# Regarding Parcel.marshall()/Parcel.unmarshall()

Tags: android, serialization, marshalling, parcelable

I have question regarding serialization of complex objects.

The documentation of marshall() explicitly states the following:

*"The data you retrieve here must not be placed in any kind of persistent storage (on local disk, across a network, etc). For that, you should use standard serialization or another kind of general serialization mechanism. The Parcel marshalled representation is highly optimized for local IPC, and as such does not attempt to maintain compatibility with data created in different versions of the platform"*

Does this means that I'm safe if...

1. The marshalled data does not leave the device,
2. Double check that the API level where the data was created stays the same, and
3. Discard the data if it doesn't (probably because the device was upgraded).

Another one. Does the binary format differ between manufacturers in the same API level, or does it stay the same, potentially making 1) unneeded?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as i know (but i may be bloody liar) the format didn't change from 1.* API level, try to `marshall` on 1.* or 2.* level and `unmarshall` on 5.*, but even if it is true it can change on any future level

Comment: It looks like you're right, I've marshalled a large object with Android 6.0, saved it to disk and tried unmarshalling it on Android 2.3.5 and Android 3.0, without problems. I'll throw an exception in my code and discard the file when the version does not match && Android > 6.0, just in case. In any case this is not going to be much of a problem since the data is not going to leave the device. Thanks for the info.